# Minimal surfaces defined on the plane is the plane itself

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, riemann-surfaces, minimal-surfaces

My problem is:

Let $S$ be a surface given by the graph of a smooth function defined on all points of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that if $S$ is minimal, then $S$ is a plane.

Just by looking at the differential equation for the defining function dosend solve the problem. Can someone help me with this one?

Comment: This looks like the Bernstein Problem. There are several ways to attack it. You may want to look at https://maths.anu.edu.au/files/CMAProcVol34P2-Athanassenas.pdf

Comment: @humanStampedist: Exactly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_problem

Comment: oh, this thing has a name.. Nice move professor! Thanks for the ref!

Comment: @humanStampedist I have a little problem with that material. Why the existance of $u$ is equivalent with the existance of $\phi$?